# Updating Ubuntu's ARM64 toolchain

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compilation, arm64

I was trying to compile an ARM64 linux kernel with CONFIG_KASAN and CONFIG_KCOV and it seems that the compiler toolchain I have is too old. I get an error message stating

```
Cannot use CONFIG_GCC_PLUGINS: your gcc installation does not support plugins, perhaps the necessary headers are missing?
```

How can I upgrade my ARM64 toolchin?